# Find string in HTML content

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to find solution for finding exact string in HTML content.

Let's assume that we have this HTML Content

```
<p><strong>Vestibulum</strong> rutrum</p>
<p>Some other html content<p>
```

ans I want to find string "Vestibulum rutrum" in this text and wrap it with shortcode. So after the parsing it would look like this

```
<p>[shortcode]<strong>Vestibulum</strong> rutrum[/shortcode]</p>
<p>Some other html content<p>
```

My idea was to use regex for it but I wasn't able to com up with the right algorithm for it.

Do you have any other idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

strpos will help you find it: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

You could also use str_replace if you know the exact string.

Regex is still probably the best way.  Have you tried this site?

http://regexr.com/

Comment: thank you. i know the regexr site but regex is not my strong site :)